# Curious about Python namespace with dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces

I am using Python3.7 and I am curious about the namespace of the dictionary.
Here is My question.

Let's define a ***dict*** first:

```
r = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}
```

then we define a function:

```
def fun1():
    print(r['a'])

fun1()
```

**Output: [1, 2, 3]**

then We define another function:

```
def fun2():
    r = {'a':[10,11,12],'c':[7,8,9]}
    fun1()

fun2()
```

**Output:[1, 2, 3]**

Why isn't the output of fun2 **[10,11,12]**, as r is redefined inside the function ***func2***. But it seems to be pointing to what we defined at the beginning. Does scope not apply to dictionaries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: "Does scope not apply to dictionaries?" – it does, which is why ``fun2.<locals>.r`` is not in the scope of ``fun1.<locals>``. What makes you assume the former scope is visible from the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the new r to be visible inside fun1, you have to define fun1 inside fun2 like this :

```
def fun2():
    r = {'a':[10,11,12],'c':[7,8,9]}
    def fun1():
      print(r['a'])
    fun1()
```

Otherwise you can pass r as a parameter to fun1 like this:

```
def fun1(r):
    print(r['a'])

def fun2():
    r = {'a':[10,11,12],'c':[7,8,9]}
    fun1(r)

fun2()
```

Comment: What’s the difference between define fun1 outside and inside fun 2？

Comment: The difference is just that if it is outside it won’t take into account the new value of `r` that is inside, it will take into account the `r` outside.

Answer (score 0):

`r = {'a': [10, 11, 12], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}` is only visible inside `fun2`. `fun1` will only see `r` that was defined in the "global" namespace.

Comment: Why can't fun1 see the r defined in the previous function?

Comment: Because that's how Python scopes work, there isn't really a better answer